# Check if a message sent has a domain from a text list on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Newbie python programmer here!

I am currently working on a discord bot, I have a file called list.txt which contains some domains (examples):
`google.com facebook.com twitch.tv youtube.com`
I tried to use a file with separated lines like:

```
google.com
facebook.com
twitch.tv
youtube.com
```

but it doesn't read lines (I tried `.readlines()` rather than `.read()` too, doesn't work), so I ended up writing all of them in a single line. The list I'm working on has over 1000 domains.

I wrote a command which detects if the domain is passed as an argument and it works with the one line spaced domain list (ex: `!domaincheck facebook.com` will answer `Present in the domain file`,
the command below:

```py
@bot.command()
async def domaincheck(ctx, arg):
        domainlist = arg
        if domainlist in open("list.txt").read():
            await ctx.send("Present in domains file")
        else:
            await ctx.send("This domain is not in the domains file")
```

However, when I want to set up it as a `on_message` event to automatically fetch any domain from all messages, it doesn't work. My current script is:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    domainlist = open("list.txt").readlines()
    if domainlist in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("I detected a listed domain in your message")
```

I get a

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

How can I use a list instead of a string? From what I've seen I should use `if "domain.com" in message.content:` but I can't since I got over a thousand domains in my file. What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you mean to do `if message.content in domainlist:` but that likely wouldn't work either, seems that you actually want to do `for domain in domainlist: if domain in message_content: await .... break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First load your domains from the `domains.txt` file to a python list:

```
google.com
facebook.com
twitch.tv
youtube.com
```

```py
with open("domains.txt", "r") as file:
    domains = file.read().split("\n")
```

Then search for domains in messages content:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for domain in domains:
        if domain in message.content:
            await message.reply(f"I detected a listed domain in your message: {domain}")
```